# How do I print very large value of N%M using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example if I give input 5 and 18. I want to convert 5 to five ones i.e. `(11111)%18 = 5`. I can do this using `print(int(('1'*N))%M)`
but I want same with very large numbers i.e. `N=338692981500, M=1838828`
now my N should be converted in `111111111111111111........1111 (Ntimes)%1838828 = 482531`. When I did this I'm getting memory error.

```
    N,M=map(int,input().split())
    print(int(('1'*N))%M)

338692981500 1838828   
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "testing.py", line 687, in <module>  
  result=int ('1'*N)%M;  
MemoryError
```

Comment: You get a memory error because you are creating an integer with `338692981500` digits, not because you are then trying to find the modulo of that number.

Comment: This is probably some kind of coding challenge, and the point is that you *don't* try to construct `'1' * N` first..

Comment: then how should i create a very long integer?

Comment: @sukesh you should try to figure out a way to compute the result without creating the very long `111....1111` string.

Comment: @sukesh use mathematics to simplify your expression. The number specified by `N`, is equivalent to `sum(10**i for i in range(N))`. Take this along with the property of modulo arithmetic which says `(a+b)%c` can be expanded to `(a%c + b%c)%c` and see if you can simplify the calculation into something tractable.